# Memory leak in MemberQ

Tags: bugs, memory

**Bug introduced in 10.0.0 and fixed in 10.0.2**

---

Consider the following code.

```
Clear[f, g]
f[x_, list_] := Function[i, If[MemberQ[list, {i, i}], N[x], 0]];
g[x_, list_] := Function[i, N[x]];
v = f[2, {{1, 1}}];
w = g[2, {{1, 1}}];
```

Then, running the code below reveals that `v` consumes much more memory than `w`, despite their similar definitions.

```
MemoryInUse[]
v[1] & /@ Range[100000];
MemoryInUse[]
w[1] & /@ Range[100000];
MemoryInUse[]
```

Why is this so?

Comment: In version 10.0.2 I get the output 85137712,

87550608,

88353400.  I shall mark this accordingly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This appears to have been a bug that was present in version 10.0, but has been fixed in version 10.1.

I can reproduce the behaviour using *Mathematica* version 10.0.1, but the leak does not occur in versions 7.0.1, 8.0.1, 9.0.1, or 10.1 (all on Win7 64-bit).  I initially set `$HistoryLength = 0` to remove saved results from consideration.

I speculate that `MemberQ` in v10.0 is creating an intermediate structure for searching, and that structure is not being released after use.  If I change the code to use `!FreeQ` instead, then the leak persists.  The leak disappears if I define my own simplistic `memberQ` function:

```
memberQ[list_, v_] := Scan[If[#===v, Return[True]]&, list] /. Null -> False
```

Whatever structure `MemberQ` is building, it is not reclaimed when I call `ClearSystemCache`.

Comment: There was indeed a memory leak in `MemberQ` and `FreeQ`, introduced in 10.0.0 and fixed in 10.0.2 (and also 10.1.0).

Comment: @StefanR In general, is the list of bug fixes available anywhere?

Comment: @anon No, I'm afraid they aren't.